# Who should make server calls or local file loading in client side MVC?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

I am working on an iOS app design.

I have established a basic MVC model as follows.

I have a tableView class (V) that is displayed by a ViewController class (C) and a Table Datasource class (M) that holds an array of elements to be displayed by the tableView.
Now, in some cases, the data in the Table Data source comes from a server, and in other cases it comes from a local file packaged with the app. 
Where should the code to load the data into the Table Datasource go?

1. It can go into the view controller and it would be responsible for fetching data from server or local file and passing it to the Table Datasource class.
2. The Table Data source can contain the code that calls the server or loads the file.
3. Implement a third service class (S) that fetches server data or loads local file and have this class be called from the ViewController (C)
4. Implement a third service class (S) that fetches server data or loads local file and have this class be called from the Table Datasource (M)

In my current implementation, I am using method 3. for server based data models and method 1. for local data files.

Which method amongst these best aligns with the MVC model? Or which method amongst these is best in general and why?

Is there a 5th method that I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should definitely use option (3) or (4). It is very helpful to separate network code from non-network code and using a service class is perfect for this.

I think deciding between (3) or (4) is a matter of preference. They should be almost identical solutions (in fact, often the view controller is the data source).

I generally use option (3) and set my view controller up as the data source for the table view.

Comment: The idea in separating the data source from view controller is to ensure that the view controller does not grow to big and also to align to MVC.
And that is what created the question at hand. The question that I am trying to answer is who should be aware of where the data is coming from, the view controller or the model? Also if it is ok to have two data models (one on server and one on client) communicating without the knowledge of the view controller.

Comment: If that model (data source) creates additional re-usability on top of the service class that you would have created, then I see a reason. Otherwise, it's complete preference in my opinion. I think the service class would provide the extent of any re-usability though.

Comment: I really code for re-usability...and re-usability that matters in the scope of my application(s). If I'm ever repeating code (that's more than a line or 2), I start to question my architecture and find something better. I can't say that I've contemplated your specific problem much, probably less than you have, but re-usability is always where I start. Of course, clear/concise/maintainable code is a necessity.